# Jquery.min.js load exception 0x800a139e

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, exception, visual-studio-2012

(I modified this post to reflect comments below and now am posting error in non-mollified version.)

JQuery:  /*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
Browser: Internet Explorer (IE) v10 running on Windows 8 Pro

I am loading jquery.min.js (v1.8.3) from SiteMaster.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
```

When starting my Default.aspx file using the local IE window inside VS2012, I get an exception.

```
Exception was thrown at line 5301, column 6 in localhost:49928/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The actual part that throws the exception is:

```
if ( matches ) {
    assert(function( div ) {
        // Check to see if it's possible to do matchesSelector
        // on a disconnected node (IE 9)
        disconnectedMatch = matches.call( div, "div" );

        // This should fail with an exception
            // Gecko does not error, returns false instead
        try {
            matches.call( div, "[test!='']:sizzle" );
            rbuggyMatches.push( "!=", pseudos );
        } catch ( e ) {}
    });

    // rbuggyMatches always contains :active and :focus, so no need for a length check
    rbuggyMatches = /* rbuggyMatches.length && */ new RegExp( rbuggyMatches.join("|") );
```

If I press continue, the page loads.

Stack Trace:
    Anonymous function [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 5301
    assert [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 3801
    Anonymous function [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 5293
    Anonymous function [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 5178
    Anonymous function [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 3669
    Global code [jquery-1.8.3.js] Line 14

Any thoughts?

Comment: and u are experiencing this on IE ? which version of jquery?

Comment: The problem probably has something to do with the way you're using the library.  jQuery is not bullet-proof, and improper uses of the APIs can very often trigger exceptions deep inside the machinery. A good thing to try is to use a non-minified version of the library.

Comment: Something like an stacktrace in a non-minified jQuery would be more informative. Especially for a dynamic-typed language as JavaScript

Comment: I added the stack trace, posted the problem using a non-mollified version.  Sorry, I am new to jQuery and just downloaded the default option several weeks ago.  I also posted the version of IE that I am using and the version of JQuery (current release as of this posting).

Comment: Isn't this exception that is caught by the code in the posted try-catch block? The debugger may halt on every thrown exception, even if they are caught in another place. In other words, this exception is supposed to be thrown, but is caught by jQuery, no need to worry.

Comment: Good point and quite possibly. That said; no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to load-dependent manner

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments...

or
/jquery/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js is Wrong version for jquery-1.8.3.js

Comment: jquery 1.4.2  is good i get it from zhe code of  view-source:http://www.jquerypopupwindow.com/#how